Expected payout in a 2 player die game

You and your opponent throw a 6-sided die. The person with a larger number wins $1. If the die values are equal, neither of you wins the reward. Now, say you and your opponent have the option to pay 25 cents to add 2 to the number you roll, but neither of you will know each other's initial rolls nor whether or not one chooses to pay the 25 cents. We will only know each others' final numbers. When then should you choose to pay 25 cents to add 2 to the number you roll, and what's the expected value of playing this game?

I am trying to solve this question mathematically. I found out the Nash Equilibrium is for both players to add $2$ to the side they rolled. However, my expected payout when both the players add $2$ is quite different from the answer that was simulated in the original post, which is $\frac{73}{216}$
My working:
Scenario 1 (When both players don't pay):
Both will have an expected payout of $\frac{15}{36} \approx 0.416$
Scenario 2 (When one player pays and the other doesn't):
If the player who pays is playing optimally, they would only pay when {${1,2,3,4,5}$} is rolled, leading to an expected payout of $\frac{35}{72} \approx 0.486$, and the player who doesn't pay will have an expected payout of $\frac{1}{6} \approx 0.167$.
Scenario 3 (When both players pay):
If both the players are playing optimally, then they would only pay when {${1,2,3,4,5}$} is rolled, and by symmetry the expected payout for both the players is same:
E[Payout] = $ \frac{1}{36} \times 14 + \frac{1}{36} \times (19 \times -0.25) + \frac{1}{36} \times (3 \times 0) = \frac{37}{144} \approx 0.257 $
Table:
$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Values: (You , Opponent)} & \textbf{Opponent: Pay} & \textbf{Opponent: Not Pay} \\
\hline
\textbf{You: Pay} & 0.257 , 0.257 & 0.486, 0.167\\
\hline
\textbf{You: Not Pay} & 0.167, 0.486 & 0.416, 0.416\\
\hline
\end{array}
$
From the table, we can clearly see that the Nash Equilibrium is when both players pay. The expected payout for playing this game is therefore 0.257, but this isn't close to $\frac{73}{216} \approx 0.337$
Where am I going wrong?

are you familiar with Nash equilibrium? Your writeup gives no indication of that. $\quad$ Why must every player either pay or not pay all the time? Can't they pay some of the time?

I'm not very familiar with it. My idea was that if a player added 2 to the side, they would do so when they roll any number except 6. How should I approach this problem?

In which case I encourage you to go read up on it first. $\quad$ Your idea is wrong. Even if I rolled a 6, I'd be interested in "protecting" it in case you rolled a 4, 5, or 6 and then added 2. So it might be worthwhile for me to still spend some money for that protection.

I see. This makes sense. So the Nash Equilibrium table would be much bigger and would consider a lot more cases I assume. Could the scenario you mentioned be solved by considering cases, $E[\text{payout if I roll 6}]$ and $E[\text{payout if I roll 6 then add 2}]$ and then choosing the highest value? Where, $E[\text{payout if I roll 6}] = E[\text{payout of 6} | \text{opponent adds 2}] + E[\text{payout of 6} | \text{opponent doesn't add 2}]$? Similarly, we can find $E[\text{payout if I roll 6 then add 2}]$. What would $P(\text{opponent adds }2)$ be if this is the way to solve it?

What readings do you recommend on this topic?

If you both add $2$ only on $1,2,3,4,5$ the chance of a tie at $6$ has gone up from $\frac 1{36}$ to $\frac 19$.  The overall chance of a tie is then $\frac 14$ and by symmetry the EV for each player is $\frac 38-\frac 14\cdot \frac 56=\frac 16$

But the EV when both the players add 2 is $\frac{73}{216}$

Fussing about pronouns: "When then should you choose to pay 25 cents to add 2 to my number" should presumably be I and my, or you and your.

@Henry Sorry about that. Fixed it!

FYI - the answer was not "simulated" in the other post. Instead, David Clyde used Mathematica to simplify and differentiate the expressions. Mathematica is just doing what you or I would do to perform the calculation (though with better recall, less intelligence and more doggedness).

I make the expected values $\frac{15}{36}=\frac5{12}\approx0.4167$ each when neither pay, $\frac{26}{36}-\frac14=\frac{17}{36}\approx0.4722$ and $\frac6{36}=\frac16\approx 0.1667$ when the first always pays and the second never does, and $\frac{15}{36}-\frac14=\frac16\approx0.1667$ each when both always pay for the two extra points.

The answer to the linked question is different as it has a mixed strategy conditioned on the value of the roll: it suggests a strategy of looking at the roll and if it is $1,2,3,4,5,6$ then buying the two extra points with probabilities $\frac16,\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac12,1$ respectively, to give an expectation of $\frac{73}{216}\approx0.3380$.

Oh yes, could you tell me how we're getting these probabilities? This is the part where I am confused.

Also, to identify the best strategy using the Nash equilibrium table, can I use your method of considering "extreme" cases—where one player always pays while the other does not, and so forth—to find an equilibrium? Is this approach acceptable? I assume that considering every possible scenario, such as whether a player chooses to pay or not for each roll (while also accounting for the opponent's decisions), would be quite computationally intensive.

$"$$\frac{26}{36}−\frac{1}{4}=\frac{17}{36} \approx 0.4722$ and $\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6} \approx 0.1667$ when the first always pays and the second never does,$"$
Why is it $\frac{26}{36}−\frac{1}{4}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{26}{36}−\frac{10}{36} \times \frac{1}{4}$, since we would lose 10 out of 36 times?

@ShsTht Which step in the argument of the linked post do you not understand? It's a quite involved computation of a maximum using mathematica. It is essentially constrained optimization of the expected value. Are you asking about the case where you know the other person's strategy?

I want to know how the strategy of adding 25 cents to {$1,2,3,4,5,6$} with corresponding probabilities of $\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{2},1$ was found in the original post. I understand until the expression for expected value,  but don't understand the parts after that. Is the expression being maximized? How did they find those probabilities and the final expected value of the game.

Yes this expression is to be maximized for each player. So, for the first player we maximize the expression with respect to his probabilities $p_k$ that he can choose. By symmetry, at the same time the second player will solve the same problem with $p$ and $q$ swapped. Therefore we can solve them both simultaneouly to arrive at a solution for all variables. This solution was calculated with mathematica.

Oh yes, the solution was calculated with mathematica. I want to know how to solve it mathematically.

I showed the system of equations that was solved in my answer but I have to say that I get a different value of the expected value (but the same solution).

The Nash equilibrium is when both players cannot have a higher pay-out by changing their strategy. I think that the way to arrive at the solution is quite clearly explained in the linked post.
If I know that my opponent always pays 25 cents in case she rolls {1,2,3,4,5}, then  I can choose to pay whenever I roll {3,4,5,6}. Then I would have pay-out of $\frac{11}{36}=0.3055...$ which is better than the 0.257. So the optimal strategy in that case is not to also "pay 25 cents when I roll {1,2,3,4,5}."
Let's follow the notation from the other post and use $p_1,...,p_6$ , i.e. $p_k$ for the probabilities of player 1 to pay 25 cents when he has thrown $k$ and $q_1,...,q_6$ for player 2. I think that there is a typo in the original (but the calculation is correct) and the expected value has to be
\begin{align}
E[W_1] &= \frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 \left( p_k (P[O<k+2] - 1/4) + (1-p_k) P[O<k]\right)\\
&=\frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 \left( p_k \left(\left(\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right) - \frac14\right) + (1-p_k) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 \left(p_k \left(\left(\sum_{j=k}^{k+1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right) - \frac14\right) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 \left( p_k \left(\left(\frac16 (q_{k-2} + 1 - q_k + q_{k-1}+1-q_{k+1})\right) - \frac14\right) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 \left(p_k \left( q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} + \frac12\right) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac16 (q_{j-2} + 1 - q_j)\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 1 6 \sum_{k=1}^6 p_k \left( q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} + \frac12\right) + \frac{5}{12}-\frac1{18} (q_1  + q_2 + q_3 + q_4 + \frac1{2} q_5)\\
\end{align}
Now, since we are player 1, we want to make this as high as possible by choosing $p_k$. How we choose $p_k$ depends on whether its coefficient $\left( q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} + \frac12\right)$ is positive, negative or zero.
If the coefficient of $p_k$ is zero, then we don't want to change it because it doesn't affect the outcome. If the coefficient of $p_k$ is positive but $p_k=1$, then we want to increase it but we cannot make the probability more than 1. Similarly, if the coefficient of $p_k$ is negative but $p_k=0$, we cannot decrease it anymore.
For a Nash equilibirium we want to find a strategy in which neither of the players can change its own probability to gain an advantage. This gives a complicated system of equations and inequalities.
The following has to be true for every $k \in \{1,...,6\}$:
\begin{cases}
0\leq p_k\leq 1; 0 \leq q_k \leq 1 \\
q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} + \frac12= 0&\text{ or } (q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} + \frac12 > 0 \text{ and } p_k = 1 )\\  
&\text{ or } (q_{k-2} + q_{k-1}-q_k-q_{k+1} +\frac12 < 0 \text{ and } p_k = 0 )\\
p_{k-2} + p_{k-1}-p_k-p_{k+1} + \frac12= 0&\text{ or } (p_{k-2} + p_{k-1}-p_k-p_{k+1} + \frac12 > 0 \text{ and } q_k = 1 )\\  &\text{ or } (p_{k-2} + p_{k-1}-p_k-p_{k+1} + \frac12 < 0 \text{ and } q_k = 0 )\\
\end{cases}
You can check that this is all true if $(p_1,...,p_6)=(\frac16,\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac12,1)$ and $(q_1,...,q_6)=(\frac16,\frac13,\frac13,\frac23,\frac12,1)$.
However, when I use these values to evaluate the expected value above, I find something different that the other post: $E(W_1)=\frac{31}{72}=0.43055...$
